# Unable to feed dynamic values into rows(" : ") function VBA

Tags: vba, dynamic, rows

I'm trying to change date format of 250 rows with 15 cells in between. 
**I'm unable feed the dynamic row number to select the entire row.**

```
Sub Macro2()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Range("A2").Select
Do While i < 250
i = i + 1
j = ActiveCell.row
    Rows("j:j").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    Cells(ActiveCell.row + 15, 1).Select
    Loop
```

End Sub

I'm no professional coder. I've looked for syntax of rows in internet and it's working when given j = 2,3,4....integer but not able to execute this one. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the index for `Rows` needs to be either a numeric value, or a string similar to `"10:15"`.  You are trying to use a string of `"j:j"`, but should have just used the numeric variable `j`.

The following code would be better suited to your task:

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To 250 * 15 Step 15
        Rows(i).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Useful thing to know is also that when you declare a variable and want to use it, you don't put it in double quotes like you did `"j:j"`, you have to use

```
Sub Macro2()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Range("A2").Select
Do While i < 250
    i = i + 1
    j = ActiveCell.row
    Rows(j & ":" & j).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    Cells(ActiveCell.row + 15, 1).Select
Loop
End Sub
```

This should work fine as well. But here, as you only want to select one row, you can just use `Rows(j).Select`.

Comment: This     ** Rows(j&":"&j).select  **   is what I was trying to code. My logic is fine but not good with syntax and ended up with  ** Rows(" j &":"&j ").select ** which didn't work. Lessons learnt! Thank you.